# All browsers and Spotify stopped working today on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: snap, window, browser, spotify

As in the title, all browsers and Spotify stopped working, that gets me thinking that possibly something is wrong with all of my "windowed" apps, and it looks like it.

Reinstalling, running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` did nothing.
I have no idea what to do next to fix that, any ideas? :) Thanks!

Edit: running `sudo dmesg` i see a lot of:

```
INFO: task Xwayland:25026 blocked for more than 483 seconds.
```

Maybe something is wrong with Xwayland... will try to change to X11.

Answer (score 1):

I run Ubuntu in recovery mode, run all options that fix packages that were available there, then run the ubuntu on a normal mode and it works, hope it will help someone too.